# Need a php script for applying imark on images

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add 'Watermark' to images with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235152/add-watermark-to-images-with-php)

I am working on a website having wallpapers in it. My client wants to add the Imark on each uploaded image. When he will upload an image he will also upload an Imark image. if any one can help me in finding a php script. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think i could not explain what is required. Actually i in need of a script for adding a logo on each wallpaper. Client will upload logo and wallpaper and my script will add this logo at the left bottom side of the image. if any one can help me in finding such a script in php

Comment: Clear as mud. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean "watermark."

Try this:

[Add 'Watermark' to images with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235152/add-watermark-to-images-with-php)
[PHP Watermarking - Zubrag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452057/php-watermarking-zubrag)
[Dynamic Watermark / On-the-fly Zip Files problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336482/dynamic-watermark-on-the-fly-zip-files-problem)
[PHP watermarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726894/php-watermarking)
[SO php watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+watermark)
[Google php image watermark](http://www.google.com/search?q=watermark+image+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)